# Correctness of asymptotic expression from exact expression

Tags: asymptotics

I have the expression:
\begin{equation}
  |Q|f(n)|\Gamma|^{f(n)}
\end{equation}

Here is my solution to convert the above into an asymptotic expression:
$|Q| = 2^l$ for some $l\in\mathbb{R}$
$|\Gamma| = 2^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{R}$

Therefore we have $2^lf(n)(2^k)^{f(n)} = f(n)2^{kf(n)+l} = f(n)2^{O(f(n))}$

1. Is this correct? I just want to verify my understanding of a discussion in Sipser's Theory of Computation text.

Comment: I not sure whether I understand your notation.  Do you mean $|Q| \times |f(n)| \times |\Gamma|^{f(n)}$?  You seem to be missing some vertical lines.  Also what is the definition of $Q$, $f$, and $\Gamma$?  Do you really mean "for some", or do you mean "for all"?  If $Q$ is a function of $l$, knowing that $|Q|=2^l$ for some $l$ does not tell you anything useful about the asymptotic behavior of $Q$.  (If $Q$ is a constant, you might want to say so.)  You might want to proof-read your question and edit it to correct these issues...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because questions of the form: "This is the exercises problem, this is my solution. Please grade!" are not a good fit for this site. Please see [this related meta discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/597/). If you want to ask a *specific* question about a *specific* part of your attempt, please edit the question accordingly and it may be reopened.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It's also possible to go further: $f\cdot 2^{O(f)} = 2^{O(f)+\log f} = 2^{O(f)}$.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is correct under the assumption that $|\Gamma|$ and $|Q|$ are constant (which, from the context, is indeed the case), but can be taken a bit further, and can be made more explicit:

For every $x>0$ it holds that $x=2^{\log x}$. Therefore you get

$$f(n)|Q||\Gamma|^{f(n)}=2^{\log f(n)}2^{\log |Q|}2^{f(n)\log |\Gamma|}=
2^{\log f(n)+\log |Q|+f(n)\log |\Gamma|}=2^{O(f(n))}$$

which is somewhat cleaner.

Comment: The problem is that the last "$=$" is not defined (formally). There is a relevant answer [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9299/asymptotic-notations-with-two-exponents).

Comment: Indeed, this is the old discussion about the flaws of the Landau notation, e.g. [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use/61#61)